# HTML5 Canvas multi circle issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this code that is displaying one circle with a % value, and i'm trying to add another circle next to it who displays another % value.

To do so, i have tried to add another JS code who calls the second ID `my_canvas2` but the results are one circle with an incremental % value with no ending.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas1').getContext('2d');

var al = 0;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

function progressSim() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 7;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(80, 80, 70, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  if (al >= 65) {
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 25);
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas1" width="170" height="170" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
<canvas id="my_canvas2" width="170" height="170" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
```

I've seen some similars subjects where the issue was the closing path of the first circle, i've tried so, still the same problem. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you update the code with the code you're actually using? (The broken example). Because the above doesn't reference `my_canvas2` in the code.

Comment: Can you add the code of your attempt? The code provided, you probably got from somewhere else, and was not written by yourself, right?

Comment: @ASDFGerte. Don't think it was relevant that the code was written by them or not. Perhaps OP wanted to modify for their application, but is having difficulty. SO is still a place of learning :)

Comment: @SunnyPatel I did not downvote the question, nor was it meant to be judging in any way (while perhaps taken as such). Finding and reusing code is not a bad thing. It is interesting, because an answer should focus on the problems OP has, and e.g. debating details of above code can be of little use, if it was not written by OP. Other code was not provided. Tbh, as the question did not include the code that produces a problem, i merely intended to find out, whether a more basic error is to be expected, like using the same global variables again (my glass ball guess), or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
function progressSim(ctx, al, start) {
  let cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  let ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  let diff;
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 7;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(80, 80, 70, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function startProgress(canvas_id, progress_int_1, stop_at) {
  let ctx = document.getElementById(canvas_id).getContext('2d');
  // let start = 4.72;
  let al = progress_int_1;
  let start = 4.72;
  var sim = setInterval(function(){
    progressSim(ctx, al, start);
    al++;
    if (al >= stop_at) {
      clearTimeout(sim);
    }
  }, 25);
}

var progress_int_1 = 0;
var progress_int_2 = 0;
var sim1;
var sim2;
sim1 = startProgress('my_canvas1', progress_int_1, 50);
sim2 = startProgress('my_canvas2', progress_int_2, 80);
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas1" width="170" height="170" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
<canvas id="my_canvas2" width="170" height="170" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Working Now? @aliouawalid

Comment: No, not yet, it displays one circle only

Comment: Have you got a link to your test page? Have you inspected the element and checked for console errors?

Comment: This is weird. I can see both circles progressing in code snippet here on stackoverflow. Let me see what the issue is. [codepen](https://codepen.io/cvryn/live/LBJRXq)

Comment: @ColinGell Could not see any error in console(chrome only).

Comment: Yes i just noticed that it worked, maybe i missed up a line while i pasted the code, thank you sir @KaranBhagat

Answer (score 2):

You need to isolate your variables if you want to duplicate the functionality. This allows you to have code that is free from conflict.

This function takes in 2 parameters, the ID of your Canvas, and what percentage you want to show it to. `diff` and `start` are local variables that do not need to persist in between calls.

```js
function progressSim(id, percent) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d'),
      cw = ctx.canvas.width,
      ch = ctx.canvas.height,
      al = 0,
      sim = setInterval(progress, 25);
  function progress() {
    var start = 4.72,
        diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 7;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(80, 80, 70, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    if (al >= percent) {
      clearTimeout(sim);
      // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
    }
    al++;
  };

}

progressSim('my_canvas1', 65);
progressSim('my_canvas2', 80);
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas1" width="170" height="170" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
<canvas id="my_canvas2" width="170" height="170" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
```

Comment: The functions are nested, because the purpose of the `progress` function is tied specifically to the functionality of `progressSim`. If you end up creating another function that will need to utilize the `progress()` function differently, then you should break it out as in [Karan Bhagat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714357/1708751).

Answer (score -2):

Very simple solution, I've just copied you code and done a find and replace on it so it can be used for my_canvas2

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas1').getContext('2d');

var al = 0;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

function progressSim() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 7;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(80, 80, 70, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  if (al >= 65) {
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 25);

var ctx2 = document.getElementById('my_canvas2').getContext('2d');

var al2 = 0;
var start2 = 4.72;
var cw2 = ctx2.canvas.width;
var ch2 = ctx2.canvas.height;
var diff2;

function progresssim2() {
  diff2 = ((al2 / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);

  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, cw2, ch2);
  ctx2.lineWidth = 7;
  ctx2.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx2.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx2.textal2ign = 'center';
  ctx2.fillText(al2 + '%', cw2 * .5, ch2 * .5 + 2, cw2);
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.arc(80, 80, 70, start2, diff2 / 10 + start2, false);
  ctx2.stroke();
  if (al2 >= 45) {
    clearTimeout(sim2);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al2++;
}
var sim2 = setInterval(progresssim2, 25);
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas1" width="170" height="170" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
<canvas id="my_canvas2" width="170" height="170" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
```

Other on here may have a more eloquent solution

Comment: Repetitive code isn't very useful. We are trying to understand what the issue is when OP tried to create their implementation.

Comment: Surely the issue is a compatibility issue that he is trying to solve? By making sure the variables don't conflict will give alioua walid a solution, and means that alioua walid doesn't have to do this him/herself.

Comment: Thanks Sunny, I've edited my response that was helpfull

Comment: Okay what is with the down votes, adding this to aliouas code will work - I get it's simple but why would you waste time trying to get the old code to work when adding this works just fine.  It's basically a new function that does the same as the code that works for my_canvas1 but for my_canvas2 which is what alioua is trying to achieve, surely the code is going to be broadly the same for each.  I will remove it if someone posts a workable solution but until someone posts a working answer this one I added remains.

Comment: I've tested your code, it still displaying the first circle only.

Comment: Did you use this in addition to your code, or did you replace it with this code?

Comment: I've added your code to my previous code, and i've updated my previous post.

Comment: @aliouawalid You still haven't posted what ***you*** have initially tried. Are you just wanting 2 independent progress circles?

Comment: @SunnyPatel Yes 2 independent circle with no repetitive code, like selecting the 2 ID and each one of them have their own % , the code i had initially tried is exactly the same as Colin Gell posted, i added "2" to every variable and methode used in the previous example.

Comment: @aliouawalid I've just noticed I've got fal2se in the code - try deleting the 2

Comment: and on the setInterval method too

Comment: @aliouawalid I've tried this and it works in codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJarzq as does kboul Karan Bhagat answer